# How to change a specific word/line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like the following:

```
 gene  complement(47517..48219)
                 /gene="Sp34_10000900"
                 /ID="Sp34_10000900"
 CDS       Complement(join(47517..47660,47787..47912,48019..48164,48216..48219))
                 /gene="Sp34_10000900.t1"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /ID="Sp34_10000900.t1.cds1,Sp34_10000900.t1.cds2,Sp34_10000900.t1.cds3,Sp34_10000900.t1.cds4"
 mRNA            complement(47517..48219)
                 /ID="Sp34_10000900.t1"
                 /gene="Sp34_10000900"
```

I want to delete the `.t1` portion from all the `/gene` options only. Please suggest me how can I do this

Comment: What is the output that you wish to see ?

Comment: I just want to remove the .t1 only from the /gene section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
sed "/gene=/s/\.t1//"
```

(that is, remove `.t1` from all lines that include `gene=`) do what you intend?

Comment: I suggest you make that `sed '\|/gen=|s/\.t1//'`

Comment: @MasumBillah If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.